# Where to find the pyconfig.h when building Python for Windows?

Tags: python, windows

To use the C API of the Python interpreter you include the Python.h header. And you can [see](https://github.com/python/cpython) that the Python.h header includes a file called pyconfig.h. There is no pyconfig.h in that include folder. Which is why when I include Python.h I get an error. Now, there is a pyconfig.h.in in the main folder and at the top of it it says:

> /* pyconfig.h.in.  Generated from configure.ac by autoheader.  */

But there is no pyconfig.h that ends up where it's supposed to go (I'm guessing in the Include folder. I know on Linux you run the configure command, but not on Windows. The way to build to build Python on Windows is to run PCBuild/build.bat, and after it finishes there is still no pyconfig.h in sight. What am I doing wrong? I am calling build.bat like this:

```
build.bat -p x64
```